# :class is not calling the computed property in vue (The computed property is not being called)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, computed-properties

Code:-

```
     <!--:class="changeCalmarColor" is not working-->
<div :class="changeCalmarColor" class="content" >
 
      <div
        v-if="props.currency"
        :class="[
          'font-bold',
          { 'text-3xl': props.largeValue, 'text-center': props.center },
        ]"
      >
        {{ $options.methods.format(props.value) }}
      </div>
      <div
        v-else-if="props.millifyOnly"
        :class="[
          'font-bold',
          { 'text-3xl': props.largeValue, 'text-center': props.center },
        ]"
      >
        {{ $options.methods.millifyNumber(props.value) }}
      </div>
      <div
        v-else
        :class="[
          'font-bold',
          { 'text-3xl': props.largeValue, 'text-center': props.center },
        ]"
      >
        {{ props.value }}
      </div>
    </div>
 
<script>
import millify from "millify";

export default {
  name: "StatCard",
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "normal",
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
    },
    iconPack: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    value: {
      type: [String, Number],
      required: true,
    },
    currency: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    millifyOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    largeValue: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    center: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    format(val) {
      let millifiedVal = "";
      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(val))) {
        if (parseInt(val).toString().length > 3)
          millifiedVal = millify(val, { precision: 2 });
        else millifiedVal = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
        if (millifiedVal.charAt(0) === "-") return `-$${millifiedVal.slice(1)}`;
        else return `$${millifiedVal}`;
      }
      return val;
    },
    millifyNumber(val) {
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? millify(val, { precision: 2 }) : val;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    changeCalmarColor() {
      console.log("/////VALUE AND TITLE////", this.props.title, this.props.title);
      if(this.props.title == "Calmar Ratio") {
        if(this.props.value < 1 || this.props.value == null) {
          return "text-danger";
        } else if(1 <= this.props.value && this.props.value <= 3.00) {  
          return "text-yellow";
        } else if(1 <= this.props.value && this.props.value > 3.00) {
          return "text-green"; 
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here the line `:class="changeCalmarColor"` is not working, the computed property is never called. The binding class doesn't work. I don't know why it is not being called, I have clearly defined it. I think `:class="changeCalmarColor"` is the correct way to binding a computed property with a class. I don't understand what exactly am I doing wrong here.

I have tried to even display my computed property like `<p>HELLP {{props.title}} {{changeCalmarColor}}</p>` but it is never called. I cannot see it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

To access props you should use directly `this.propName`. You could change your computed prop to:

```
changeCalmarColor() {
      console.log("/////VALUE AND TITLE////", this.title, this.title);
      if(this.title == "Calmar Ratio") {
        if(this.value < 1 || this.value == null) {
          return "text-danger";
        } else if(1 <= this.value && this.value <= 3.00) {  
          return "text-yellow";
        } else if(1 <= this.value && this.value > 3.00) {
          return "text-green"; 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing happens, man. I removed the second class attribute and updated the `changeCalmarColor()`

Comment: I edited my answer, check again and let me know

Comment: Having multiple class attributes is actually fine, as long as only one has the `v-bind:`. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: I used the `propName` but nothing happens, no error. I have edited my question, the computed property is not being called, I don't know why it's not being called

Comment: All the `props.` you have should be removed (also in the template), the computed prop is not called because they are not valid. See other answer too.

Answer (score 0):

A computed property gets cached, [See docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

So `changeCalmarColor` runs once and then waits for dependencies to change in order to re-run again.

The reason why it doesn't run is because you have used `this.props.title` while you should use `this.title`.

So this:

```
    changeCalmarColor() {
      console.log("/////VALUE AND TITLE////", this.props.title, this.props.title);
      if(this.props.title == "Calmar Ratio") {
        if(this.props.value < 1 || this.props.value == null) {
          return "text-danger";
        } else if(1 <= this.props.value && this.props.value <= 3.00) {  
          return "text-yellow";
        } else if(1 <= this.props.value && this.props.value > 3.00) {
          return "text-green"; 
        }
      }
    },
```

Should be changed to:

```
    changeCalmarColor() {
      if(this.title == "Calmar Ratio") {
        if(this.value < 1 || this.value == null) {
          return "text-danger";
        } else if(1 <= this.value && this.value <= 3.00) {  
          return "text-yellow";
        } else if(1 <= this.value && this.value > 3.00) {
          return "text-green"; 
        }
      }
    },
```